# Unable to access protected class variables from instance in another class?

Tags: c++

I'm making a queue from scratch and I have a **Node class** and a **Queue class**. My **Node class** has two protected variables (Info,Next) and I want to access these variables from my **Queue class** when I create a new Node instance, In my **Queue class** for my Enqueue method, I need to create a new Node instance and access these variables so I Naturally do....

```
Node foo = new Node;
```

The problem is, when I go to do something like....

```
Node.Next = Rear;
```

I get an error of unable to resolve identifier Next or Info.
However, if I declare a new instance outside of my methods in my **Queue class** and try and access Node's variables, I can. It is only when I am inside a method in another class that I can't. I am newer to c++ and come from a java background. Is there a specific c++ rule I am overlooking here? Thanks in advance!

for more context as requested here is the header file for Node

```
#ifndef CLINICNODE_H
#define CLINICNODE_H

#include "ClinicPatient.h"

class ClinicNode {
public:
    ClinicNode();
    void Modify(ClinicNode ThisNode);
    void InputData(int x);
    virtual string toString();
protected:
    ClinicPatient Info;
    ClinicNode Next;
};

#endif /* CLINICNODE_H */
```

Here is my constructor for ClinicNode

```
#include "ClinicNode.h"

ClinicNode::ClinicNode() {
    Info = ClinicPatient();
    Next = NULL;
}
```

here is my ClinicQueue Header

```
#ifndef CLINICQUEUE_H
#define CLINICQUEUE_H

#include "ClinicNode.h"

class ClinicQueue {
public:
    ClinicQueue();
    void addRear(ClinicPatient ThisPatient);
    ClinicPatient removeFront();
    void Modify(int Position, ClinicPatient ThisPatient);
    void clearQueue();
    ClinicPatient getInfo(int Position);
    ClinicNode getNode(int Position);
    int getSize();
    bool isEmpty();
   // ClinicPatient[] toArray();
protected:
    ClinicNode Front;
    ClinicNode Rear;
    int Length;
};

#endif /* CLINICQUEUE_H */
```

Here is a snippet from ClinicQueue.cpp

```
#include "ClinicQueue.h"

ClinicQueue::ClinicQueue() {
    Front = NULL;
    Rear = NULL;
    Length = 0;
}

void ClinicQueue::addRear(ClinicPatient ThisPatient) {
    ClinicNode newNode = new ClinicNode;
    newNode.Info.Modify(ThisPatient);
    newNode.Next = Rear;
    Rear = newNode;
    Length++;
    if(Length == 1) {
        Front = Rear;
    }
}
```

Where in this example, I try and create a ClinicNode called newNode. From there I try and access newNode's variables Info and Next, however the compiler points out that Info and Next are unresolved identifiers.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code you are describing? It is hard to understand your issue based on text descriptions rather than code snippets

Comment: `Node foo = new Node;` does not compile.  Do not confuse pointers and objects, and don't use `new` without a reason.  `Node.Next` is invalid since `Node` is a type, not an object.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem.

Comment: `protected` is effectively `private` to everyone except subclasses. If `Queue` is a subclass of `Node` it is time for a rethink.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not trying to make Queue a subclass, Queue is just a class that handles operations on Nodes such as enqueue, dequeue, removeFront, etc.

Comment: @CoryKramer Added more context to the post

Comment: Right, that's the way it should be. But that means that `Queue` cannot see `Node`'s `protected` members. Off topic, it looks like ClinicNode.h includes itself. Harmless, but odd.

Comment: @user4581301 If Queue can't see it how come I can declare a new instance outside of a method at the top and access that instances variables. What I want to do works outside of Queues methods but not in them.

Comment: @user4581301 I updated my post with as much information I could provide for the problem at hand